# How to skip a given release stage after declining in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have created given release pipeline in Azure DevOps:

1. Scale up Web App
2. Deploy application to slot
3. (pre-accept) Swap slots
4. Delete all slots
5. Scale down Web App

Decline stage 3 stops all release pipeline and to handle this I must manually deploy stage 4. But what I want is to deploy stage 4 automatically after decline stage 3.

I was trying searching something in documentation, but I found nothing.

So my question is: Is it even possible? Have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If the trigger you choose is **After stage**, you deploy stage4 after stage3, which means that the stage4 depends on stage3, so stage4's deploy is affected by stage3. Therefore, when you decline stage3, it is impossible to deploy stage4 automatically. You can only choose to trigger it manually.
[image]

If you want to continue deploying stage4 automatically after stage 3 is canceled or failed, then make stage 4 independent of stage 3, you can select the trigger of stage 4 as **After release**.
[image]

Comment: Ok, so it turns out that my case is impossible to define, your second way would be okay, but it has one major disadvantage: stage 4 is deployed before stage 3.

Comment: @bpel,The work around I can think of is adding a sleep task to the agent job of stage4.